# How to make a blacklist for blocks

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to develop a blacklist system for blocks for my server and this is how it should work: In the config.yml there are names of the materials of the blocks that are not allowed to be placed. Then a check is made for each placed block whether the material is contained in config.yml.

Here is my code:

```java
package de.blocklog.blocklog;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.util.List;

public final class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event){
        Block block = event.getBlock();
        Material material = block.getType();
        Player placer = event.getPlayer();
        double x = block.getLocation().getX();
        double y = block.getLocation().getY();
        double z = block.getLocation().getZ();
        List<String> bannedmats = this.getConfig().getStringList("banned-blocks");

        for(World w : Bukkit.getWorlds()){
            for(Player p : w.getPlayers()){
                if(p.hasPermission("blocklogsystem.see") || p.hasPermission("blocklogsystem.*"))
                    p.sendMessage("[BLOCKLOG] Player " + placer.getDisplayName() + " placed " + material + " at X:" + x + " Y: " + y +" Z: "+ z);
                
                if(material.name().equals(bannedmats))
                    p.sendMessage("[BLOCKLOG] Player " + placer.getDisplayName() + " placed an illegal " + material + " at X:" + x + " Y: " + y +" Z: "+ z);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow it doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you go into more detail about "it doesn't work"? What are the failure modes? What's actually happening?

Comment: In addition to the above, could you provide your `onEnable` code?

Answer (score 0):

Yout need to register your Event in the onEnable Method like:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // Plugin startup logic
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, your provided information is a bit vague but I've recently implemented exactly this feature except with the banned blocks stored in memory as an `ArrayList` of `Material` objects.

Effectively what I do is make use of the `.contains()` method of an ArrayList object to check for presence of a given block in a list of blocks.

All this considered here is the basic run down, assuming you've already developed parsing your config.yml data into specifically an ArrayList of Material objects that looks something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Material> PlacementBanned = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        PlacementBanned.addAll(Arrays.asList(Material.BARRIER, Material.COMMAND_BLOCK,
                Material.CHAIN_COMMAND_BLOCK, Material.REPEATING_COMMAND_BLOCK, Material.COMMAND_BLOCK_MINECART,
                Material.WATER, Material.LAVA, Material.STRUCTURE_BLOCK, Material.STRUCTURE_VOID));
    }
```

Firstly, I **highly** recommend you use a separate class for the listener. like this:

Main

```
package myPlugin;

import myPlugin.myPackage.myListenerClass;

import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public static Plugin instance;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        instance = this;
        
        PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
        pm.registerEvents(new myListenerClass(), this);
    }
}
```

myPackage.myListenerClass

```
package myPlugin.myPackage;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class myListenerClass implements Listener {

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST, ignoreCancelled = false)
    public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {

        Block block = event.getBlockPlaced();
        Material blockType = block.getType();

        if (PlacementBanned.contains(blockType)) {

                event.setCancelled(true);
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Note, LOWEST priority means it will be queued up in the first of 5 batches of all methods triggered by the listener in your code.